# How to configure binary name in Go without changing path

Tags: go

I'm developing a small tool with Go. And recently, I noticed that the tool needs to be invoked from a shell script, because it's using shell function.

Assume my tool is called `atool`. So, `go build` generates a binary `atool`, and my tool has a Go structure as `github.com/myaccount/atool`. Now, i want to build `atool-cli` binary with `go build`, and invoke it from shell script `atool`. How can I achieve this?

The only way coming in my mind is change go structure as `github.com/myaccuont/atool-cli`. But I don't want to do this because the  already announced, and also, the path seems a bit funny name.

Comment: `go build -o atool-cli github.com/you/atool`

Comment: thank you. and i'm using `gox` for building my app. I'll check does `gox` support this option.

Comment: @elithrar maybe make this an answer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just to make my comment "official":

```
go build -o atool-cli github.com/you/atool
```

Comment: yeah but what about when using `go install`?  looking to get something working with the default of writing it to `$GOPATH/bin`   ... maybe your answer could add how to put it there? Doesn't `go install` do more behind the scenes too, more than go build does?

Answer (score 9):

One way packages structure themselves as a library, and provide main packages is to put their main entrypoints in subdirectories.

You can have a `main` package in `github.com/myaccount/atool/atool-cli`, which imports `github.com/myaccount/atool` and implements `func main()`. Some packages with multiple commands even have a `/cmd/` directory with multiple cli tools that can be built (see [`camlistore`](https://camlistore.org/code) as an example)

Comment: This sounds more smart way. But one problem is that the structure become a bit complicated. Thanks for your knowledge.

Comment: appreciate the real world example